# Track div height during rendering from an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a book using json data in reactjs. I am using map() to lay down my data in the correct format.

The whole purpose of this application is to generate a PDF that can be later printed. I want to create a footer after each page that shows the page number and date. I need to calculate exactly how much space my text takes on each page so that I can pop in a footer div after a certain height is reached.

Here is the current code without a footer:

```js
    <div className="book">
      {datedChats.map((group, j) => (
        <div key={j}>
          <p className="header"><Moment format='dddd, MMMM Do YYYY'>{group.date}</Moment></p>
          {group.chats.map((chat, i) => (
            <div key={i} className={classnames({
              message: true,
              me: chat.name === 'redacted1',
              her: chat.name === 'redacted2'
            })}>
            {chat.message}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

I need to calculate the offsetHeight of the parent div each time the map() is looping, so I can either show the footer or the next message instead. How do I put such logic in here?